# C# Attach Property Control base class

Tags: c#, properties

I would like to know how to add a property from one of my user controls to the base controls property list.  Is this possible?

```
So what I am doing is this:

private static List<LabelType> ConvertControlCollectionToList(Control customContainer)
    {
        LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Clear();

        foreach (Control c in customContainer.Controls)
        {
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Add(new LabelType());
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().Name = c.Name;
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().Top = c.Top;
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().Left = c.Left;
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().Height = c.Height;
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().Width = c.Width;
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().Font = c.Font;
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().Text = c.Text;
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().DataColumn = c.?????
            LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Last().Rotation = c.?????
        }

        return LabelTypeList.LabelProps;
    }
```

I have two properties at the end of the list which are custom to my usercontrol but I need to add them to the base control class so when I load the collection back into a form my settings for DataColumn and Rotation are accessible.  Does that make sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, for example, that your control is a `TextBox` named `txtFirstName` and you want a property representing the text of that `TextBox` on your `UserControl`:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return txtFirstName.Text; }
    set { txtFirstName.Text = value; }
}
```

**Edit**

Given the edit to the question, no you can't do exactly what you're asking for (add your property to those of the base class). You can, however, check to see if a particular control is an instance of your `UserControl`, and gather those properties if it is. To do so, use this:

```
private static List<LabelType> ConvertControlCollectionToList(Control customContainer)
{
    LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Clear();

    foreach (Control c in customContainer.Controls)
    {
        LabelType lt = new LabelType();

        LabelTypeList.LabelProps.Add(lt);

        lt.Name = c.Name;
        lt.Top = c.Top;
        lt.Left = c.Left;
        lt.Height = c.Height;
        lt.Width = c.Width;
        lt.Font = c.Font;
        lt.Text = c.Text;

        YourUserControlType uc = c as YourUserControlType;

        if(uc != null)
        {
            lt.DataColumn = uc.DataColumn;
            lt.Rotation = uc.Rotation;
        }
    }

    return LabelTypeList.LabelProps;
}
```

(I removed the call to `Last()`, as that is a LINQ extension method and will cause the entire list to be traversed every time you set a property).

Comment: Downvoter care to elaborate as to why? This appears to be exactly what he's asking for.

Comment: Adam, in your answer is YourUserControlType a type class or the actual UserControl?  If it is the usercontrol how can I access it from my biz tier without causing a circular reference?

Comment: It's a type, hence the suffix of `Type` ;)

Comment: I am getting this error now when when I use MyType t = c as MyType

Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'ScanProTypes.UserLabelType' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: +1 for removing those horrifying repeated calls to Last(), although I might have been inclined to use an object initializer.

Comment: Nathan, my first thought on seeing that error would be to check whether ScanProTypes.UserLabelType actually inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control or not.

Comment: @Joel: I would have used an initializer, but I didn't want to change the structure of the code more than I needed to, and the initializer wouldn't have actually optimized anything, it would have just looked prettier ;)

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, you can use [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265152(VS.95).aspx) to provide this behavior.  This is how things like [Grid.Row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.row.aspx) works.

In Windows Forms, you'll want to use an [Extender Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43(VS.71).aspx).

Note that neither option truly adds properties to the base class - you can't change the base class structure in a subclass.  They do add properties available at design time that are usable with the control.

Comment: The impression I got was that he wanted to do the opposite: expose a property from a child control on the parent control.

Comment: Not sure what he's after, at least not 100% sure.  Maybe Nathan can chime in with more details.

Comment: Please see the edit to my original post above and maybe it will be more clear.